# Hexapdf: trying to draw white box, but its not appearing

Tags: ruby, pdf, rubygems, prawn

When I run my code, my white box does not appear.  I need a white box to cover existing images, text, so I can add new text. If I change the color to background_color: [255,255,180], the box is a transparent yellow.  However, I need a non-transparent white.

```
require 'hexapdf'
require 'pry'

doc = HexaPDF::Document.open('template.pdf')
pages = doc.pages

box = HexaPDF::Layout::Box.create(
  width: 500, height: 500, content_box: true,
  background_color: [255,255,255]
  )

pages.each do |p|
  canvas = p.canvas(type: :underlay)
  box.draw(canvas, 20, 100)
end

doc.write("template_with_white_box.pdf")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `canvas = p.canvas(type: :overlay)` for this to work because the underlay canvas draws beneath the existing page whereas the overlay canvas draws above the existing page.